# How to Split Fill of Text Horizontally In Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, text, logo, fill

I've seen this answered before but for some reason I can't seem to find it anywhere - I'm trying to split text horizontally like in the following logo designs:

[image]

You can see how the colors in the text are actually split 50 / 50 - there isn't a gradient applied. But when I try to replicate the first logo, the only idea that I can come up with is to split the background colors in half, expand the text, and then create a clipping mask. Unfortunately, that idea didn't work, (I was left with only white text):

[image]

So how do you split text colors in half (horizontally) and also keep the white outline? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recreate the effect in the first logo above (except for the text being italic), follow these steps:

1. First, click on the text and hit Expand

[image]

2. Click OK

[image]

3. Select the text and click Object --> Path --> Offset Path

[image]

4. Determine the width of your Offset Path (or outline)

[image]

5. Create a rectangle with no fill and no outline that cuts through your text horizontally

[image]

6. Use the selection tool to select your empty rectangle and all of the "inside shapes" of your text

[image]

7. Go to pathfinder and hit Divide

[image]

8. Use the selection tool to select the bottom half of your text. Change shapes to desired color.

[image]

Now the fill of your text is split in half horizontally.